# jquery selection with 2 attribute value

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to select an html element with jquery using its attribute value.

I use `$('td[i=0]')` and it works correctly. What if i want to use 2 attribute together.

For example, I want to select **td** element with attributes i="0" and j="2" .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just append them, e.g.:

```
('td[i=0][j=2]')
```

This works for pretty much any selector, adding them together *without* a space makes it check for the attribute on the same element.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$('td[i=o]' 'td[j=2]')` ?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery OR Selector:

```
$("td[i=0], td[i=2]")
```

jQuery AND Selector:

```
$("td[i=0][i=2]")
```

Comment: your first answer is wrong, that will try and look for the element `td[i=0]` inside the element `td[i=2]`, the second param is used as a context so `sidebar = $('sidebar'); $boxes = $('.box',sidebar)`